# FATAL EXCEPTION: inference. Cannot copy to a TensorFlowLite tensor from a Java Buffer

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, image-classification

I was developing an [Image Classifier app](https://github.com/m-murillo/fashion-mnist-tflite) in Android Studio with [MNIST-fashion database](https://github.com/zalandoresearch/fashion-mnist#loading-data-with-other-machine-learning-libraries), but I have a little problem. When I try to run the app, I have this common error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot copy to a TensorFlowLite tensor (serving_default_conv2d_input:0) with 3136 bytes from a Java Buffer with 9408 bytes.`

I know this might be the mismatch of input tensor from the model and the buffer that I have in my code. But It's too confusing because my code automatically fits the size of the image from the model and all the info it needs. So I was wondering where is the error...

```
// Reads type and shape of input and output tensors, respectively.
    int imageTensorIndex = 0;
    int[] imageShape = tflite.getInputTensor(imageTensorIndex).shape(); // {1, height, width, 1}
    imageSizeY = imageShape[1];
    imageSizeX = imageShape[2];
    DataType imageDataType = tflite.getInputTensor(imageTensorIndex).dataType();
    int probabilityTensorIndex = 0;
    int[] probabilityShape =
        tflite.getOutputTensor(probabilityTensorIndex).shape(); // {1, 10}
    DataType probabilityDataType = tflite.getOutputTensor(probabilityTensorIndex).dataType();

// Creates the input tensor.
    inputImageBuffer = new TensorImage(imageDataType);
```

Maybe this is the problem... I'm creating imageShape like this {1, height, width, 1}, and the data type is FLOAT32, so it is supposed to be {1, height, width, 4}, right?

Another reason could be the metadata. But I populate the model with metadata and I have a *.json* and I don't know how to use it.

Note: If u want the note book to do the *.tflite*, [there u go](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zvHCe9iasUnex6wgStY1tHtIbhPC1uVz?usp=sharing).

Comment: "Thanks in advantage" is incorrect and also not helpful to include in a question. Please see [no thanks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it). Also, when someone answers the question, it is inappropriate to edit the question to make their answer insufficient. See this post on [matryoshka questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625/etiquette-for-russian-doll-questions). It is better to just [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and link back to this one if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The tensor buffer size is determined by datasize (float32: 4bytes) * flat size of the tensor shape (1 * height * width * 1).

So the above code snippet needs to prepare an float input tensor data with the shape (1, height, width, 1) instead of the shape (1, height, width, 4).

Comment: I tried with that and didn't work, it trows me the same error... But in a different line^^ Seems like we are fixing the code ty :3